# How to add constraints to TableView on TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have `TabBar`, `SearchController` and `TableView`...

To fix the problem with the black screen, I added following string to my TableViewController that places `SearchController` on itself:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

But, I receive next problem - after I move to the next controller and back to the TableViewController table is placed below the navigation bar.

How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: It looks like an issue I got once with contentOffset. Could you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29791791/2618071 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in your tableviewController `viewDidLoad` method:

```
yourTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's work! How i can do this only after the transition from prev viewController. I I tried to do it in prepare method of unwind segue, but it did't work. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: @IliaFedorov  since your original problem is solved, please ask another question I will help you there for new problem

Comment: Okey, thank you. Here is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751035/how-to-setup-settings-for-tableview-before-back-transition-from-previous-viewcon

Answer (score 2):

select your viewcontroller and uncheck the under top bars i think its help for you

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that is not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Select your ViewController and Select the None in under top bars.

And you need to update the code in ViewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden=true
}
```

Comment: Yes, now the table is not placed under navigationBar, but i navBar is needed to me.